# Why is my form freezing when I invoke BeginConnect?

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets, asynchronous, tcp

I'm using this example from [Asynchronous Client Socket Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-client-socket-example)

```
using System;  
using System.Net;  
using System.Net.Sockets;  
using System.Threading;  
using System.Text;  

// State object for receiving data from remote device.  
public class StateObject {  
    // Client socket.  
    public Socket workSocket = null;  
    // Size of receive buffer.  
    public const int BufferSize = 256;  
    // Receive buffer.  
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];  
    // Received data string.  
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  
}  

public class AsynchronousClient {  
    // The port number for the remote device.  
    private const int port = 11000;  

    // ManualResetEvent instances signal completion.  
    private static ManualResetEvent connectDone =   
        new ManualResetEvent(false);  
    private static ManualResetEvent sendDone =   
        new ManualResetEvent(false);  
    private static ManualResetEvent receiveDone =   
        new ManualResetEvent(false);  

    // The response from the remote device.  
    private static String response = String.Empty;  

    private static void StartClient() {  
        // Connect to a remote device.  
        try {  
            // Establish the remote endpoint for the socket.  
            // The name of the   
            // remote device is "host.contoso.com".  
            IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry("host.contoso.com");  
            IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];  
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);  

            // Create a TCP/IP socket.  
            Socket client = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,  
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);  

            // Connect to the remote endpoint.  
            client.BeginConnect( remoteEP,   
                new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);  
            connectDone.WaitOne();  

            // Send test data to the remote device.  
            Send(client,"This is a test<EOF>");  
            sendDone.WaitOne();  

            // Receive the response from the remote device.  
            Receive(client);  
            receiveDone.WaitOne();  

            // Write the response to the console.  
            Console.WriteLine("Response received : {0}", response);  

            // Release the socket.  
            client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);  
            client.Close();  

        } catch (Exception e) {  
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());  
        }  
    }  

    private static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {  
        try {  
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.  
            Socket client = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;  

            // Complete the connection.  
            client.EndConnect(ar);  

            Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}",  
                client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());  

            // Signal that the connection has been made.  
            connectDone.Set();  
        } catch (Exception e) {  
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());  
        }  
    }  

    private static void Receive(Socket client) {  
        try {  
            // Create the state object.  
            StateObject state = new StateObject();  
            state.workSocket = client;  

            // Begin receiving the data from the remote device.  
            client.BeginReceive( state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,  
                new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);  
        } catch (Exception e) {  
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());  
        }  
    }  

    private static void ReceiveCallback( IAsyncResult ar ) {  
        try {  
            // Retrieve the state object and the client socket   
            // from the asynchronous state object.  
            StateObject state = (StateObject) ar.AsyncState;  
            Socket client = state.workSocket;  

            // Read data from the remote device.  
            int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);  

            if (bytesRead > 0) {  
                // There might be more data, so store the data received so far.  
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer,0,bytesRead));  

                // Get the rest of the data.  
                client.BeginReceive(state.buffer,0,StateObject.BufferSize,0,  
                    new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);  
            } else {  
                // All the data has arrived; put it in response.  
                if (state.sb.Length > 1) {  
                    response = state.sb.ToString();  
                }  
                // Signal that all bytes have been received.  
                receiveDone.Set();  
            }  
        } catch (Exception e) {  
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());  
        }  
    }  

    private static void Send(Socket client, String data) {  
        // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.  
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);  

        // Begin sending the data to the remote device.  
        client.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,  
            new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), client);  
    }  

    private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {  
        try {  
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.  
            Socket client = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;  

            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.  
            int bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);  
            Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to server.", bytesSent);  

            // Signal that all bytes have been sent.  
            sendDone.Set();  
        } catch (Exception e) {  
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());  
        }  
    }  

    public static int Main(String[] args) {  
        StartClient();  
        return 0;  
    }  
}
```

I'm in the process of programming the networkside of my application, right now just some testing, but I have an odd problem. My UI freezes when I call the StartClient method. This example is in a seperate class and just call it in my mainform with: `AsynchronousClient.Startclient();`

I need to mention that right now there is not a server listening, but why is the form freezing, afterall i'm not using the synchronous example. I have read on the internet that it could be because the form thread must be run from the main thread, but I haven't changed anything regarding to this. In my opinion the form should just continue to function even if it can't connect.

How do I achieve this? I can give you my code, but I think it's not very relevant. Just as I said I call the StartClient method from the AsynchronousClient class, it's static, and then call it somewhere in my main class. (in a button right now).

Not relevant I think, but I know the packets are send, I have checked this with wireshark.

Comment: `AsynchronousClient.Startclient()` uses the the asynchronous `BeginConnect` of the `Socket` class, you're right.
However, `Startclient` itself is not async since right after it calls `BeginConnect` it blocks by using `connectDone.WaitOne()`, a reset event that is released only after the `Socket` actually connects.

Comment: So if I understand correctly I need to make this method somehow async? I'm going to find some tutorials for that, don't know how to do that right now, unfortunately. Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my comment, `AsynchronousClient.Startclient()` is not async since it uses `ManualResetEvent` to block.

I personally recommend to not use the `Socket` directly. It really depends on what you are doing but there are better APIs for remote communication.

HTTP, Json-RPC, gRPC, ZeroMQ, etc...
Depends on your use case. Using raw TCP sockets is **almost** always an overkill.

Anyway, to make the method truly asynchronous you would have to get rid of the `WaitOne` calls.
The reason the `WaitOne` calls are there in the first place, I believe, is to make the code more readable, but you could theoretically do the "Sending" logic in the "Connecting" callback and do the "Receiving" logic in the "Sending" callback.

Like this

```
using System;  
using System.Net;  
using System.Net.Sockets;  
using System.Threading;  
using System.Text;  

// State object for receiving data from remote device.  
public class StateObject {  
    // Client socket.  
    public Socket workSocket = null;  
    // Size of receive buffer.  
    public const int BufferSize = 256;  
    // Receive buffer.  
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];  
    // Received data string.  
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  
}  

public class AsynchronousClient {  
    // The port number for the remote device.  
    private const int port = 11000;  

    // ManualResetEvent instances signal completion.  
    private static ManualResetEvent connectDone =   
        new ManualResetEvent(false);  
    private static ManualResetEvent sendDone =   
        new ManualResetEvent(false);  
    private static ManualResetEvent receiveDone =   
        new ManualResetEvent(false);  

    // The response from the remote device.  
    private static String response = String.Empty;  

    private static void StartClient() {  
        // Connect to a remote device.  
        try {  
            // Establish the remote endpoint for the socket.  
            // The name of the   
            // remote device is "host.contoso.com".  
            IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry("host.contoso.com");  
            IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];  
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);  

            // Create a TCP/IP socket.  
            Socket client = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,  
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);  

            // Connect to the remote endpoint.  
            client.BeginConnect( remoteEP,   
                new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);  


        } catch (Exception e) {  
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());  
        }  
    }  

    private static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {  
        try {  
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.  
            Socket client = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;  

            // Complete the connection.  
            client.EndConnect(ar);  

            Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}",  
                client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());  

            // we do it here now...
            Send(client,"This is a test<EOF>");  
        } catch (Exception e) {  
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());  
        }  
    }  

    private static void Receive(Socket client) {  
        try {  
            // Create the state object.  
            StateObject state = new StateObject();  
            state.workSocket = client;  

            // Begin receiving the data from the remote device.  
            client.BeginReceive( state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,  
                new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);  
        } catch (Exception e) {  
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());  
        }  
    }  

    private static void ReceiveCallback( IAsyncResult ar ) {  
        try {  
            // Retrieve the state object and the client socket   
            // from the asynchronous state object.  
            StateObject state = (StateObject) ar.AsyncState;  
            Socket client = state.workSocket;  

            // Read data from the remote device.  
            int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);  

            if (bytesRead > 0) {  
                // There might be more data, so store the data received so far.  
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer,0,bytesRead));  

                // Get the rest of the data.  
                client.BeginReceive(state.buffer,0,StateObject.BufferSize,0,  
                    new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);  
            } else {  
                // All the data has arrived; put it in response.  
                if (state.sb.Length > 1) {  
                    response = state.sb.ToString();  
                }  

                // after all is done, we shut down the socket
                client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);  
                client.Close();  
            }  
        } catch (Exception e) {  
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());  
        }  
    }  

    private static void Send(Socket client, String data) {  
        // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.  
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);  

        // Begin sending the data to the remote device.  
        client.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,  
            new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), client);  
    }  

    private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {  
        try {  
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.  
            Socket client = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;  

            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.  
            int bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);  
            Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to server.", bytesSent);  

            // We do it here now...
            Receive(client); 
        } catch (Exception e) {  
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());  
        }  
    }  

    public static int Main(String[] args) {  
        StartClient();  
        return 0;  
    }  
}
```

This should work. With this, `StartClient` doesn't block. It returns right after it calls `BeginConnect`.

However, this is a very old and dirty API, that is why I would think twice before using native `Socket`s.

You can explain your goal better and I'll try to offer something better.

Comment: Wow, thank you! Can't test right now, will do that tomorrow. Now I am thinking about it, it is indeed isn't really necessary to put those receive and send functions outside the callback. What I want to do is creating a peer to peer application. Just with one socket per connection. I want to design this whole thing myself. Including packet structure and reading this out on the other end. I haven't really thought about other options. It is necessary to easily get the raw bytes. Do you have a better idea? Otherwise I will mark you questions as answered tomorrow. :)

Comment: @Mart1250 Are you doing it for exercise? If so, it is fine. However, using the raw `Socket` API is rarely a good idea in production, since it is very error prone. A good alternative which is comparable to raw sockets in term of performance and footprint is NetMQ. It is a wrapper around raw sockets, it deals with buffering, framing, error handling and offers several patterns like router/dealer, pub/sub, etc... `It is necessary to easily get the raw bytes` NetMQ doesn't handle serialization, so you get to interface with the raw data/bytes.

Comment: Actually I haven't done this before, so it is a challenge for me, but it is for a real application. I am aware that I have to deal with buffering, and that it is not guaranteed that a message is received on the other end. But, now you are talking about NetMQ, I'm doubting. They support sending and receiving raw bytes according to: https://netmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/receiving-sending/ So yeah, what's right... I wonder whether I have to deal with 'more data' coming in like in the socket example, before I process it. Or is NetMQ accounting for that?

Comment: Does NetMQ somehow guarantees that all data is in when I'm going to process it? BTW, I will mark your solution as answered, it works, it was the main question anyway.

Comment: @Mart1250 The problem with raw `Socket` API is that you have to handle framing by yourself. You can send `Hello` from the client, and the server will receive `He` and `llo` as separate messages, and you would have to know when to cut the message by using special characters of sort. `NetMQ` handles that for you, each message is divided into arbitrary frames, e.g. header frame, msg id frame, body frame, and methods `ReceiveFrameBytes`, `ReceiveFrameString` guaranty to return whole frames (e.g. "Hello" instead of "He" and "llo")

Comment: @Mart1250 This is a good example https://netmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/request-response/

Comment: Thank you! Im going to experiment with it and check if it's suitable. I think I understand where you are talking about. In your example with 'he' and 'llo' each 'frame' in the socket example get's put into the 'response' variable. Right? So that means that you need to concat these 'frames' together. I have thought about how you should know how long a message is. So what I wanted to do if i'm going to use sockets(not sure anymore), is sending a header with the length of the message, that way you know what to concat and what's part of the next message.

Comment: Maybe a bit simplified, but you get the idea, I think. ;p

Comment: @Mart1250 Sending the length of the message is one way. Another common way is sending messages together with a divider/separator that denotes the end of the message. Note how in the example you gave in your post, you send the message to the server with an "<EOF>". The server (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example) then knows to look for that <EOF> and parse everything prior to that as a single message/frame.

Comment: Yeah that is an option, but because I need deal with encrypted data that is not possible. Thanks for all your help! :)